# Executing a function on button press (tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to write a small program that allows the user to click a button to select files, type in a stock number, and then click a button to rename those files.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames

root = Tk()
root.title("Photo Renamer")
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

directory = ''
arrayOfFiles = []
stockNum = 0

def getStockNumber():
    stockNum = stockNumber.get()

def selectFiles():
    selectedFiles = askopenfilenames()
    # Switch our files from a tuple to an array.
    # arrayOfFiles = []
    for i in selectedFiles:
        arrayOfFiles.append(i)
    return arrayOfFiles

def rename(array): # array will be arrayOfFiles
    # Separate file names from the whole file path.
    fileNames = []
    for i in range(len(array)):
        fileNames.append(os.path.basename(i))

    count = 1
    directory = os.path.dirname(array[1])
    for file in directory:
        oldFileName = '%s/%s' % (directory, file)
        newFileName = '%s/gma%d_%d.jpg' % (directory, stockNum, count)
        os.rename(oldFileName, newFileName)
        count += 1

# "Stock Number" label
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Stock Number: ").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

# Entry box
stockNumber = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7)
stockNumber.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

# "Select Files" button
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Select Files", command=selectFiles).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=(W, E))

# "Number of Files" label
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Number of Files: ").grid(column=1, row=3, sticky=W)

# "Rename" button
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Rename", command= lambda: rename(arrayOfFiles)).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(W, E)) # command=rename

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
stockNumber.focus()

root.mainloop()
```

I can select the files, and type in the stock number, but when I click the rename button, it gives me this error in the console:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/Python/gui.py", line 56, in <lambda>
    ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Rename", command= lambda: rename(arrayOfFiles)).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=(W, E)) # command=rename
  File "C:/Users/.../Desktop/Python/gui.py", line 32, in rename
    fileNames.append(os.path.basename(i))
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 232, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 204, in split
    d, p = splitdrive(p)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\ntpath.py", line 139, in splitdrive
    if len(p) >= 2:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

list.append() requires a string - you're giving an integer.
Change

```
fileNames.append(os.path.basename(int))
```

to

```
fileNames.append(os.path.basename(str))
```

The error was thrown within the Python code (`os` module, [see the docs over here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) ([Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename))) when it tried to get the `len(int)`, which is impossible (since `int` doesn't have the method `__len__`)

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    fileNames.append(os.path.basename(i))
```

In your above code, `i` is an integer and [os.path.basename(path)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) expects a pathname like string.

When iterating over a list, you can direcly iterate through items.

```
for file in array:
    fileNames.append(os.path.basename(file))
```

or if you want to use indexes, you can do

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    fileNames.append(os.path.basename(array[i]))
                                      ^^^^^ notice accessing an item using index
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(array):
```

Instead of

```
for i in range(len(array)):
```

Comment: I had to use `for i in range(len(array)):` because my array is a list of the file names.

Comment: then u have problem that on `fileNames.append(os.path.basename(i))` because it is a getting value an integer not a string .instead of string use **filepath** `fileNames.append(os.path.basename(filepath))`. or u can also check it with the index of an array `fileNames.append(os.path.basename(array[i]))`

Comment: Most likely, `range()` expects an integer and `array` is a list which makes your suggestion wrong.

Comment: @Lafexlos you said it is wrong.just see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15182804/python-3-30-typeerror-object-of-type-int-has-no-len

Comment: In that link range's parameter is integer. In your code, array is a list. When you pass a list to a range function, it'll result in `TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got list.` or something like that. So you should either use `range(len(array))` or direct `for i in array` discarding `range` overall.

Comment: You can easily check this behaviour by trying to run `range([1,2,3])` in your interpreter.

Comment: kk. I forget about it is list